# using UIView animateWithDuration: delay: Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode5, animatewithduration

I am trying to use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
} completion:^ (BOOL completed) {}         ];
```

however no matter what number I put for the delay, there is no delay.
I am trying to have a series of buttons fade in one after the other when another button is touched. So I use a series of UIView animate  with various lengths of delay but they all show up at the same time no matter what time delay I enter.  Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: Could you show us a bit more of your code in context? The snippet above has an empty animation block...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, the values `animateWithDuration`and `delay` are **`float`** values, and should be as `1.0` and `2.0`

**Opinion:** if your code is at the `ViewDidLoad` Method, try to move it to a separated function

Secondly if you are not able to do it by this context, jump to another, or make a walk around such as using

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay
```

Another walk around is to set the `delay` to 0, and place the subsequent `UIView` animation blocks in the `completion` block of the previous `animateWithDuration` statements

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
        //Leave it empty
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

// Your code goes here
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:
   UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        } completion:^ (BOOL completed) {}];
    }];
```

**PS:** some properties are not supported to be animated such as setting the text within the animation block so after the delay is over, the animations begin which immediately changes the text as that change is not animatable.

in the text animation case, To do what you want, change the text in the completion block as follows:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:2.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                 animations:nil
                 completion:^{
                     lbl.text =  @"My text" ;
}];
```

Also `backgroundColor` is **NOT** animated in `UIView`. Instead, use `backgroundColor` property of the view's `layer`:

```
[[controller layer] setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor anyColor] CGColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can code it at `viewWillAppear`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:2.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                     animations:^{
                         //yourAnimation
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Animation is finished");
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer! Accept now!

Answer (score 1):

Before you implement please read it 
duration: The total duration of the animations, measured in seconds. If you specify a negative value or 0, the changes are made without animating them.
delay   : The amount of time (measured in seconds) to wait before beginning the animations. Specify a value of 0 to begin the animations immediately.
options

-Use float values for both of above parameters
  - It would be ice if you define your animation operation in separate routine &

call it appropriate location like in ViewDidAppear/viewWillapear.

> ```
> Use function like this & set your UI Element properties like this:
>  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
>                           delay:0.3
>                         options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
>                      animations:^{
>                          [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
>                          [yourviews setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
>                          self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
>                      }
>                      completion:^(BOOL finished){
>
>                          // You next action to perform after completion;
>                      }];
> }
> ```

Happy coding , hope it will help you.